# JAVA, can ResultSet has numberOfColumns() so that we don't even care the number of returned columns in a select query?

Tags: java

Here is my issue, I have a select query that join many tables & each table has many columns. I just want to select everything & give the result as a text (with tab dilimited) to user so that user can copy that text into excel & play with the result in Excel.

If that is the case then i don't need to specify the fields in the `select` query, just `select * from` is enough. However, i got stuck cos I need specific number for `getString` ex `getString(1);` `getString(2);`

```
String sql="select * from tb1 join tb2 .......";
preparedStmt=myCon.prepareStatement(sql);
ResultSet results=preparedStmt.executeQuery();
String text="";
while(results.next()){
    int no=results.noOfColumns; //here is what i need
    for(int i=0; i<no; i++){
       String s=results.getString(i+1); 
      text+=s+"\t";
    }
    text+="\n"; 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `ResultSet` contains an associated `ResultSetMetaData` which has all the information about the columns in the `ResultSet`.  You just need to pull it out and grab the number of columns:

```
    ResultSetMetaData metadata = results.getMetaData();
    int no = metadata.getColumnCount();
```

You can go take a look at [the `ResultSetMetaData` API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html) for all the other things you can do with it.